# create 2D surface which exactly covers given irregular surface

Tags: nurbs-surface

I want to make a 2D surface which exactly follows the undulations of another surface. If the given surface looks like the attached one; how can I create another surface which exactly covers it without leaving any gap between their point of contact? Specifically I have a 2D surface which needs to become the top face of a cube that results in a 3D volume with undulations on top. The original starting image can then be discarded. [image]

Comment: with a Shrinkwrap modifier perhaps? You could also bake the heights and use a Displace modifier? Please give more details?

Comment: Why do you need that? Are you trying to map an image? Then just need a texture. Please explain further. [Edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: I edited my question. Please have a look.